# 'horizontal dimensions mismatch' error when adding row of ones to matrix in Octave

Tags: matrix, octave

I am attempting to add a row of ones to a pre-existing matrix. I want to know why the following code does not work, and what I should do instead.

```
A = zeros(25, 5000);
A = [ones(1, columns(A)) A]
% I get an error message: "horizontal dimensions mismatch (1x5000 vs 25x5000)"
```

However, if I wanted to add a column of ones to a pre-existing matrix, I can do that easily without getting an error message, using practically the same method that failed above.

```
A = zeros(25, 5000);
A = [ones(rows(A), 1) A]
% no error message, A becomes a 25x5001 matrix with the first column as a column of ones
```

Why does this method work for adding a column but not work for adding a row? What other method should I use for adding a row of ones to my matrix?

Comment: This sample is from Andrew's ML course, I've also faced such a problem :D

Answer (score 2):

You can add a row using the following syntax:

```
A = [A; ones(1, columns(A))] % the key here is the semicolon
```

The reason it works for a column is because of the matrix dimensions. Suppose you have a matrix with `m` rows and `n` columns, now you can easily add a single column with `m` rows to the matrix using:

```
A = [ones(rows(A), 1) A] % dimensions match
```

Now, by using the following syntax:

```
A = [ones(1, columns(A)) A]
```

You are trying to add a column with `n` rows hence the dimension mismatch error.

Answer (score 2):

`[ A B ]` is the same as `[ A , B ]`, and concatenates `A` and `B` horizontally.

`[ A ; B ]` concatenates `A` and `B` vertically.

See [the official MATLAB documentation on concatenation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/redefining-concatenation-for-your-class.html). (I know you're using Octave, it's the same syntax.)